# Warning: json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have installed couchbase on a remote linux machine, and now want to access this on windows using php scripts. I am using putty on windows 7.

My code is below:

```
if(extension_loaded('couchbase')) {    
    $cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://23.99.27.188:8091');  
    $bucket = $cluster->openBucket('beer-sample');  
    $get = $bucket->get('Demo');  
    echo json_encode($get); }  else  {  
      echo "Error";  
  }
```

But this gives the error:

```
Warning: json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null in C:\xampp\htdocs\couchbase\index.php on line 28
```

Comment: `json_encode()` probably can't encode what `$bucket->get()` returns. JSON encoding can basically just handle plain text data like strings, numbers and such.